# list view and details view in django

Tags: python, html, django, pycharm

i want to create django project with two templates main list and details from the main list  using genetic views List view and details views.
the main list work but not work details list.
this my code can somebody to help me ?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
    model = Test,
    queryset = Test.objects.all(),
    context_object_name = "test_list",
    template_name='blog\test_list.html')),


url((r'^(?P<pk>\d+)-(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
    context_object_name="test_list1",
    model=Test,
    template_name='blog\Test_details.html'
    ), name="test"),

]
```

html code test_list

```
{% for test in test_list %}
<h2> <a href="{{test.id}}">{{test.Title}}</a></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

html code test_details

```
  <h2>{{ test.Title }}</h2>
```

Comment: A) what is the problem? B) show the views. Please.

Comment: BTW, your `urls.py` appears to be wrong, extra `]`...

Comment: the problem is i cant view second urls test details

Comment: copy paste wrong i dont have extra ]

Answer (score 0):

Your link doesn't match your URLs: you're just passing the ID in your link, but the URL pattern is expecting the link and the slug.

Comment: Well maybe you should pass the slug as well, so that it matches? Or, if you don't want to pass the slug, change your url pattern so that it's not expecting it?

Comment: i dont understand you

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a couple of typos:

First in urls, you should change this:

```
url((r'^(?P<pk>\d+)-(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
```

to this:

```
url((r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
```

Second, (again for the DetailView) your context_object_name is set to `test_list1` but your template uses `test` (the two should match; considering there is no list in this detail view, I would change them to `test`).

Third, your template_name is set as `blog\Test_details.html` with the capital `T` while your html file is actually with lower case `t`

Comment: he says the list view works, so for the detail view (his last sample of code) his template calls `{{ test.Title }}`, that's why I think it should be `test`. To be more clear, the detail view is not a list, so there will be no `{% for %}` tags in that template

Comment: now the problem is the second template is empty not show me details from my database

Answer (score 0):

yeah that correct we success(just delete -(?P[-\w]+) ) to connect first and second template but the second template my Test.Title is empty not show me details from my database,if i use {%for%} show me error message